# how does visual studio determines the active solution configuration?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, configuration, solution

I am using VS 2013 and created a custom solution configuration -- "Debug with Flag" - "Any CPU". We have central version control system, where we checkin our code. For some reason everyones' VS environment has this new configuration as active. I don't want this to show as active for others unless they explicitly change it. Also i didn't find option to set default active configuration on VS. Any ideas, why everyone is getting this new custom config as active one?

Comment: you can go and pick a different config in your standard toolbar

Comment: i know i can pick... its just that everyone else is getting this new configuration as default active configuration and i am not sure why. Supposed to be whatever they have earlier, usually "Debug". Now their environments switched to "Debug with Flag" configuration.